# Big O for the minimum of two functions

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I would like to calculate the big O for a function $f$ defined as
$$
f(n) = \min \{g(n), h(n)\}.
$$

Then, I think it holds that
$$
f(n) = O(g(n)) \quad \& \quad f(n) = O(h(n)).
$$

Of course, one of them is not a tight upper bound though. Is there any counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. As $f(n)$ is the minimum between $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ it is clear that

$$f(n)\leq g(n) \hspace{10pt} \text{ and } \hspace{10pt} f(n)\leq h(n)$$

that is

$$f(n)=O(g(n)) \hspace{10pt} \text{ and } \hspace{10pt} f(n)=O(h(n))$$

where the constant is just 1.